# How to color files in IntelliJ Rider according to modified status in Git?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider, color-scheme

I recently reinstalled IntelliJ Rider version 2023.1.1 after using a previous version for some years. Previously, newly-added files would display with green text and modified files would display with blue text. These colors would persist until I committed those changes. Now when I modify a file, it will display as blue, but only until I save my changes to disk. Newly-added files appear as white instead of green. I want the filename to stay colored blue/green until I commit my changes.

I have my directory mapping for my project directory set to use git as its VCS (under `Settings | Version Control | Directory Mappings`) and I have modified files set to display with a blue file status color in `Settings | Version Control | File Status Colors`. Disabling this color setting prevents the filename from changing to blue when I modify it.

Comment: They should remain colored blue/green until you commit your changes.
There is too little information that we can work with. I suggest opening a support ticket so JetBrains support could take look into logs and your setup specifically.
An issue can be in a name of a folder or symlink being used. Or a location (network drive or local). Also we need to see what is the `git status` output